# Downloaded themes don't show the main menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have downloaded themes for Drupal 7, and successfully installed them. When I make the downloaded themes the default one, everything works fine, except the main menu which is missing.

Can you please help me with this? The menu is enabled in the themes.

If I switch back to the Bartik theme, the main menu appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your "Main Menu" block is disabled. Main menu appears as a block. So go to admin/structure/block and enable the main menu block in some region for your theme.

Comment: Most themes (e.g. Bartik, Omega, Zen, etc) implement the main and secondary menus in code, not with blocks

Comment: Yes Thanks for that. the main menu had to be assigned to a position. and i was not getting this in any tutorials. Thanks a TON. sory i cannot up vote you